# Change NSLayoutConstraint not working and View keep going back

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to change my width constraint of View. I have connected the width with IBOutlet inside my View Controller. However, it does not work.

Try to animate it what's going on, actually the View keep going back to its original position.

Here is the code:

```
_providerExpSearchInputWidth.constant = 1000.0f;
[_providerExpSearchInput layoutIfNeeded];
```

Anyone can advise?

Comment: `updateConstraintsIfNeeded` instead of `layoutIfNeeded` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have your view tell autolayout to layout its subviews immediately first so that your layout constraints are completely known. Then you should set a new constraint and in your animation block you will again tell autolayout to layout its subviews immediately. Since you're making this call in the animation block, all of the changes will be animated.

You can try something like this:

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
_providerExpSearchInputWidth.constant = 1000.0f;

[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

This is from the Apple Documentation on layoutIfNeeded:

Use this method to force the layout of subviews before drawing. Using the view that receives the message as the root view, this method lays out the view subtree starting at the root.